# Why does my samsung galaxy s4 say 'Charging Paused,Battery Temp too High'?

Tags: charging

Ok so i have already brought a new battery and done a factory reset and tried different chargers and still says it is over heating . Please anyone got any ideas or solutions?

Comment: 1. Does the warning come up on normal (not fast) charging? You can check by charging with earlier (non fast) chargers 2. Replace the battery ( old Battery ) and check on normal charge

Answer (score 0):

There might be a fault with the battery temperature sensor, due to which it detects high temperature every time the battery temp rises a bit over the normal  (which is common when you use the phone too much or you're charging it).

Does the phone feel ***very* hot** when this is shown?  If not, then the sensor has to be replaced,  and take your phone to an authorized service centre.